# Pandas concetenation using list

Tags: python, pandas, list, concatenation

I have the following list

```
list= ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
```

furthermore i have the dataframes
df1
df2
df3 with the same dataframe structure

Now I would like to concetenate the three dataframes using the list instead of saying

```
df= pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

If I try

```
df= pd.concat(list)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

If I try

```
df = pd.concat([globals()[i]for i in list])
```

I get

```
KeyError: 'df1'
```

How can I use the list for concatenation?

Comment: don't create/access variable names programmatically, use a container. If you can type `['df1', 'df2', 'df3']`, you can type `[df1, df2, df3]`

Comment: @mozway Ty, but how can I change ['df1', 'df2', 'df3'] to [df1, df2, df3]

Comment: just don't type the quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check `eval`

```
l = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
out = pd.concat([eval(x) for x in l])
```

Comment: Someone is going to give you flack for using eval... but not me :)

Comment: @Shmack yes they may ~ :-) but work for me most of time ~

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `globals()` for that... Store the DataFrames in a dictionary instead:

```
dfs_dict = {
    'df1': df1,
    'df2': df2,
    'df3': df3,
     # others...
}
```

Then you can define a function that given a list of the `df` names/ keys, returns a list of the corresponding DataFrames

```
def get_dfs(df_names):
    return [dfs_dict[name] for name in df_names]
```

Finally, you can use it with `pd.concat`

```
df_names = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
df = pd.concat(get_dfs(df_names))
```